# Почему json приходит не весь?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

Отправляю в ответ на запрос json

```
    // POST parser/upload
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Post(IFormFile file)
    {
        var fileStream = new FileStream(environment.WebRootPath+"/Files/"+ file.FileName, FileMode.Create);
        file.CopyTo(fileStream);
        var root = Parser.Parse(fileStream);

        if (root != null)
        {
            var jsonRoot = new JsonResult(root);
            jsonRoot.ContentType = "application/json";
            return jsonRoot;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

root представляет из себя Section.cs:

```
public class Section
{
    private static int newId;
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }

    public Section ParentSection { get; set; }
    public List<Section> ChildsSections { get; set; }

    public bool HasParent { get => Level > 0 || ParentSection != null; }
    public bool HasChilds { get => ChildsSections.Count > 0; }
    public int ChildsCount { get => ChildsSections.Count; }
}
```

При отправке запроса приходит только часть json-a:

```
{"id":0,
 "name":null,
 "text":"Text of Section0",
 "level":0,
 "parentSection":null,
 "childsSections":[
      {"id":1,
       "name":"SectionName1 ",
       "text":"Text of      SectionName1",
       "level":1
```

Почему так происходит?

[image: Ответ на запрос]

Comment: А какое содержимое jsonRoot показывает отладчик?

Comment: @XelaNimed отладчик показывает правильно, полностью.

Comment: А что на стороне клиента/браузера? Что показывает в пакете (если Chrome, то вкладка Network)?

Comment: @XelaNimed добавил скрин

Comment: Неожиданный конец JSON... Смотрите значения в jsonRoot, а конкретней Section (перевод строки, спец.символы JSON и т.д.)